# MLR random forest multi label get feature importance

Tags: r, multilabel-classification, mlr

I am using multilabel.randomForestSRC learner from mlr package for a multi-label classification problem
 I would like to return  the variables importances

The getFeatureImportance function return this issue :

code:

```
getFeatureImportance(mod)
```

Error:

```
Error in checkLearner(object$learner, props = "featimp") : 
Learner 'multilabel.randomForestSRC' must support properties 'featimp', but does not support featimp'
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)). Include the code you have tried and set out your expected answer. Check out [mre] and [ask]

Comment: As the error tells you. There is no method in mlr for `multilabel.randomForestSRC` that extracts the feature importance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use extract the variable importance using `randomForestSRC::vimp`, using the example from [here](https://mlr.mlr-org.com/articles/tutorial/multilabel.html):

```
library(mlr)
yeast = getTaskData(yeast.task)
labels = colnames(yeast)[1:14]
yeast.task = makeMultilabelTask(id = "multi", data = yeast, target = labels)
lrn.rfsrc = makeLearner("multilabel.randomForestSRC")
mod2 = train(lrn.rfsrc, yeast.task)

vi =randomForestSRC::vimp(mod2$learner.model)
plot(vi,m.target ="label2")
```

[image]